# Copy element field value in list to corresponding element

Tags: c#, linq

Basically, is there a way to write this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < modelOne.PaymentsPerDate?.Count; i++)
{
    modelOne.PaymentsPerDate[i].Payment = modelTwo.PaymentsPerDate[i].Payment;
}
```

using LINQ?

Answer (score 0):

Not really.  LINQ is "Language Integrate *Query*".  It's not really intended for modifying.

Now, if you wanted to abuse the process, this might work:

```
modelOne.PaymentsPerDate.Zip(modelTwo.PaymentsPerDate, (m1, m2)=> m1.Payment = m2.Payment);
```

Comment: Dang, I forgot to change something in my code sample. Regardless, I think this is the solution I was looking for.

Comment: You also need to enumerate the `Zip`ped enumerable for the side-effects to take place. Which is exactly why you shouldn't use LINQ with side-effects. Please don't do that.